# Why doesn't g++ emit this constructor-related noexcept warning with `-fpic` enabled?

Tags: c++, optimization, gcc, g++, fpic

I have next code:

```
#include <exception>
#include <cstdlib>

void g() { throw 1; }
void (*p)() = g;

template <class T>
void f(T) noexcept (noexcept (T())) // warning 1
{
  p();
}

struct A { A() { } };           // warning 2

int main()
{
  try { f(A()); } catch (int) { }
  return 1;
}
```

And with next options:
`-fno-pic -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -Wnoexcept`
g++ throw next warnings:

```
noexcept03.C:16:6: warning: noexcept-expression evaluates to 'false' because of a call to 'A::A()' [-Wnoexcept]
noexcept03.C:21:12: warning: but 'A::A()' does not throw; perhaps it should be declared 'noexcept' [-Wnoexcept]
```

But why when I use `-fpic` instead of `-fno-pic` `g++` doesn't throw any warnings?

**EDIT:**
GCC version - 4.7.2

Comment: Which version of gcc are you using for compilation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning is not issued in the `-fpic` case, because the compiler assumes that the constructor `A::A()` can throw.

When compiling PIC code, GCC assumes that every global name can be overridden by symbols from other modules. Hence, with absence of an explicit `noexcept` declaration, GCC must conservatively assume that such a function can throw exceptions, even if it can statically prove that the version it's seeing now, cannot.

For reference, see the bug and the patch here http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=29323#c7 (code has changed a little since, but it started like this)

An example, where the above is applicable:

```
/* inline */ int f() { return 0; }

int g() noexcept (noexcept(f())) { return f() + 1; }
```

---

So, this is the immediate reason "why" there's no warning. What follows is what I think about it.

However, C++11 says:

> 7.1.2 Function specifiers [dcl.fct.spec]
>
> 4 An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in
>   which it is odr-used and **shall have exactly the same definition in
>   every case** (3.2).

i.e. for inline functions, if a function is determined to not throw, GCC can assume that every potential override of such a function cannot throw as well.

In that sense, GCC is being excessively conservative with inline functions and both in the original test case and in the above example with the `inline` keyword uncommented, GCC ought to issue the warning even when `-fpic/-fPIC` is used.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for answer. Where do you get this 
`When compiling PIC code, GCC assumes that every global name can be overridden by symbols from other modules` I mean some book/source? Please provide link.

Comment: @Pepelac, the source is the GCC source code :) By the way, this behavior is not exclusive for PIC code, it's also the same for weak functions and some other cases.

Comment: Thanks again I already found where it's implemented in GCC code, but i think probably you get it from some manual)